# Looking for proof of linearity: the sum of big-Theta is big-Theta of the sum.

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm working on problems relating asymptotic notations. And I stumbled on this easy-looking statement, which asserts that with $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$\sum_{k \in S} \Theta(f(k)) = \Theta\left(\sum_{k \in S} f(k)\right)$$
There's some necessary clarifications here. On the left-hand side, the notation $\Theta(f(k))$ denotes an anonymous function, say $g(k)$, with the property that $g(k)$ is $\Theta(f(k))$, so it would be clearer to restate the problem as
$$\sum_{k \in S} g(k) = \Theta\left(\sum_{k \in S} f(k)\right)$$
At this point, I realized our functions, on the left-hand side and inside the $\Theta$, are not functions that map from $\mathbb{Z}$ (something like $3n^2 + 1 = \Theta(n^2)$, functions just eat the integer $n$), but rather, from the set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, namely the power set $P(\mathbb{Z})$ (like in the assertion, functions eat the whole subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}$). But now I don't have any definitions of big-$\Theta$ notation dealing with this kind of functions.

I'm stuck to come up with a way to get through this. Maybe my interpretation of the problem is wrong? I need some help from you guys.

Comment: I think you overcomplicated the notation $k\in S$. It just means that the sum does not necessarily runs through all integers $k$ but rather a sumbest of it. For exmaple if $S=\mathbb{Z}^+$ then $\sum_{k\in S}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty$. Note that $S$ is fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sums and Products of Big Theta Notation (CLRS)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522776/sums-and-products-of-big-theta-notation-clrs)